# How to pass an array as an input to shellscript/bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to read an array`HSPACE` from a text file and then execute the following piece of code for each element of the array separately. Is is possible to do this using shell script?

```
awk 'NR==8 {$1="     " a }1'  a=$HSPACE  spacingcontrol.vls > tmp.vls && mv tmp.vls spacingcontrol.vls 
awk 'NR==8 {$2="  " b "      "}1'     b=$HSPACE spacingcontrol.vls > tmp.vls && mv tmp.vls spacingcontrol.vls
```

spacingcontrol.vls is as follows:

```
thk_bl      n BC      GEOM        CV
  0.24         1       axl         1

PITCH             xc          yc   
0.80000000            1.0         1.0

 1 INFLOW    h_min   h_max     Node per RadCRv
0.01   0.01       5.

  NZONES
  1
  RADIUS      XC        YC      h
  0.00        0.87      0.740     0.002
```

The `INFLOW` and `h_min` are the variables that take the value of `HSPACE`

Comment: `bash` arrays and `awk` arrays are two separate things, and whatever the value of `HSPACE` is, it is probably a third different thing. Can you show an example of what `spacingcontrol.vls` looks like, and what change you want to make?

Comment: @chepner Added it as a part of the question for your reference.

Comment: How do you actually set `HSPACE`?